# FileUpload element if submit fails, how to set it from failed request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a form with FileUpload button (DotNet mvc) when user hits submit, all data is received on serverside correctly. However if there is a problem with any of the other form fields, the form is loaded back with model, but the FileUpload is empty. How do I go about doing this so that on error, fileupload still retains the previously being uploaded file?
Thanks

Comment: I would check out [mcve] as that will assist you in accomplishing asking your question. However, one solution is have an ajax submission that validates all fields but the form field and if that returns successful, then upload and process the form. You can always do client side validation to validate the form before it gets submitted also but server side validation is more secure.

Comment: Thanks, The form error is not with any fields on the form, its the in depth data checking on the server that returns with an error hence form is reloaded and user is informed that they are creating a duplicate record (for example)..In this case the FileUpload is empty

Comment: seems like you'd need to check for the error before uploading... you could, for instance, send an ajax call to a controller that checks the fields first... if all is ok, then send the whole form to the main controller.  (I don't think you can get the local-side file path from the browser's input type=file control... unless it's an objectURL)

Comment: In my opinion, You can use client side validation, When there is a problem with any of the other fields, The form will show error message without submitting. So that fileupload will still keep the file.